# ChromeDriver is null when testing on a different PC

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem/bug when i try to use new ChromeDriver. After using launch4j to create a .exe file and starting it everything except the ChromeDriver, which is null, is working fine.
On my main computer everything works as usual.

Im using Java on my main computer but not on the Virtual Machine, since I need to distribute it to others without it

So my question is am i missing something?

Comment: I would check the exception there... output to a log or something like that.  Could be the lack of chromedriver executable on the other machine, incorrect path to it, or some other dependency that's missing.

Comment: Thank you, it just so happens that the dependencies for Selenium were not getting build by intellij